http - httpd redirect not working with virtualhost, but with .htaccess
I've a strange issue with two Nagis-core servers installed on physical Rocky linux 8.10 servers.
I tried everything to make http - https redirect work.
But it does not work of I use the typical setup with virtualhost for port 80 and a virtualhost for port 443. It also does not work if I put the rewrite rules in the /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf file and the correct certs and key int the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file.
This basic setup works on a virtual server with Rocky linux 8.10, but not on my physical servers.
But on my physical servers the same rewrite rule works, if I put it in the .htaccess file which I save in the directories (e.g. /var/www/html).
Any ideas what can prevent http -> https redirect when stored in virtualhosts files, but work when same redirect is used in .htaccess?
Thanks.
I put the rewrite rules in the /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf file and the correct certs and key int the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file.
.htaccess?
